# How to expand months in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data as below

```html
+-----+---------+----------+
| TYPE|DTIN_MNTH|DTOUT_MNTH|
+-----+---------+----------+
|    A|  2022-03|   2022-05|
|    B|  2022-04|   2022-04|
|    C|  2022-05|   2022-07|
+-----+---------+----------+
```

I want to expand the DTIN_MNTH and DTOUT_MNTH in rows as below,

```html
+-----+---------+
| TYPE|     MNTH|
+-----+---------+
|    A|  2022-03|
|    A|  2022-04|
|    A|  2022-05|
|    B|  2022-04|
|    C|  2022-05|
|    C|  2022-06|
|    C|  2022-07|
+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

From Spark 2.4, you can use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html) built-in function to generate array of months between two dates, then use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) to expand array of months. You can then reformat your expanded column to month format.

It gives you the following code, with `input` your input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = input.select(
  F.col('TYPE'),
  F.explode(
    F.sequence(
      F.to_timestamp(F.col('DTIN_MNTH'), 'yyyy-MM'),
      F.to_timestamp(F.col('DTOUT_MNTH'), 'yyyy-MM'),
      F.expr('INTERVAL 1 MONTH'))
  ).alias('MNTH')
).withColumn('MNTH', F.date_format(F.col('MNTH'), 'yyyy-MM'))
```